# Get data which is multiple times nested from "Firebase Realtime Database" in Angular

Tags: json, angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, multidimensional-array

I'm working with Angular 9 and the Firebase Realtime Database

Currently I'm able to get the data from the database, but my problem is, that the data which I need is nested multiple times and I don't know how to display only the values of the most (twice) nested data on my HTML.

Typescript:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { AngularFireDatabase } from '@angular/fire/database';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-os-skills',
  templateUrl: './os-skills.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./os-skills.component.css']
})
export class OsSkillsComponent implements OnInit {

  osSkills: Observable<any> = null;

  constructor(private db : AngularFireDatabase) { 
    this.osSkills = db.list("/os_programm").snapshotChanges() 
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="main">
    <div class="card" *ngFor="let item of osSkills | async">
        <div class="head">
                <h1>{{item.payload.skill | json}}</h1> 
                <p>Level</p>
            </div>
            <div class="description" [ngSwitch]="item.payload.level | json">
                <div *ngSwitchDefault>
                    <div class="square_empty"></div>
                    <div class="square_empty"></div>
                    <div class="square_empty"></div>
                    <div class="square_empty"></div>
                    <div class="square_empty"></div>
                </div>
                <div *ngSwitchCase = 1>
                    <div class="square_filled"></div>
                    <div class="square_empty"></div>
                    <div class="square_empty"></div>
                    <div class="square_empty"></div>
                    <div class="square_empty"></div>
                </div>
                <div *ngSwitchCase = 2>
                    <div class="square_filled"></div>
                    <div class="square_filled"></div>
                    <div class="square_empty"></div>
                    <div class="square_empty"></div>
                    <div class="square_empty"></div>
                </div>
                <div *ngSwitchCase = 3>
                    <div class="square_filled"></div>
                    <div class="square_filled"></div>
                    <div class="square_filled"></div>
                    <div class="square_empty"></div>
                    <div class="square_empty"></div>
                </div>
                <div *ngSwitchCase = 4>
                    <div class="square_filled"></div>
                    <div class="square_filled"></div>
                    <div class="square_filled"></div>
                    <div class="square_filled"></div>
                    <div class="square_empty"></div>
                </div>
                <div *ngSwitchCase = 5>
                    <div class="square_filled"></div>
                    <div class="square_filled"></div>
                    <div class="square_filled"></div>
                    <div class="square_filled"></div>
                    <div class="square_filled"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[Datastructure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gxogt.png)

Comment: can you share the structure of your data ?

Comment: Yes sure it's the link under the HTML

Comment: ok cool, can you console log this.osSkills? just to check is it's an array or an object

Comment: it's an object and if I alter {{item.payload.skill | json}} to {{item.payload | json}} I get an array like this: {"level": 4,"skill": "Windows"}

Comment: Thanks <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/users/6518546/elmehdi">@Elmehdi</a> for your help, but I've found an answer to my question on this website: https://grokonez.com/frontend/angular/angular-8/angular-8-firebase-tutorial-crud-operations-angular-fire-example

Answer (score 0):

If you wanna get the skill you can just do:

```
<h1>{{item.payload.skill}}</h1>
```

And for the level:

```
<p>{{item.payload.level}}</p>
```

Comment: I've already tried this before but unfortunately this doesn't work for me.

Comment: what do you get with <h1>{{item.payload.skill}}</h1>

Comment: I've got nothing

Comment: I can't seem to undestand the problem you have. So you have osSkills and you want to extract all the skills from it? can you do {{osSkills | async | json }} in your template and attache it to your question.